# SORT BY value and display only those items

Tags: php, html

I am creating a project which I would like to have an html form, with a select element, and inside the select to have some values which are Country, City, Area.  What I would like is when the user choose one of the values and click the submit button to display only the products that corresponds to that value. I do not know how to do it but I would appreciate it if someone can help with the code.

Thanks.

Code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <h1>PRODUCTS</h1>
        <hr>
        <form method="post" action="">        
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="SORT BY">SORT BY</label>
                <select name="">
                    <option value="">Select One...</option>
                    <option value="country">Country</option>
                    <option value="city">City</option>
                    <option value="area">Area</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">
            </div>

        </form>

        <?php

        $query = "SELECT * FROM dropdowns";
        $query_connection = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_connection)) {
            $country = $row['country'];
            $city = $row['city'];
            $area = $row['area'];


            echo "<div class='col-xs-3'>";
            echo "<div class='well'>";
            echo "<img src='images/01.jpg' class='img-responsive'>";
            echo "<h2 class='lead'>$country</h2>";
            echo "<h2 class='lead'>$city</h2>";
            echo "<h2 class='lead'>$area</h2>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }

        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're looking for _javascript_ to have things change dynamically on changes like that.

Comment: If you are going to submit the form with POST, then on the POST page get the value of the select input. You will want to give the select a name also. `  <select name="search">
                    <option value="">Select One...</option>
                    <option value="country">Country</option>
                    <option value="city">City</option>
                    <option value="area">Area</option>
                </select>                              <?php $search = $_POST['search']; ?>`

Comment: Thanks all for ur answers. @MarieWeb your code $search = $_POST['search'] is what I was missing thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need SQL here and a way of getting the "POST" values and using them in the queries like

```
$_POST['option'] = $option;   
 $query = "SELECT * FROM dropdowns WHERE Option = '$option"
```

Still it depends what your dropdown table is like(what columns it has).
The other thing is that you have to link your FORM with the PHP using

```
action="something.php"
```

or urls ending like

```
?option=something
```

but will mean you have to split the code in 2 different files.
The second option you can use $_GET['option'] and use it in the query.

Another suggestion is to turn it all in PHP and echo the HTML parts.